Multivariate linear regression via scikit and statsmodels
want to preface this first with terminology: multivariate regression deals with the case where there are more than one dependent variables while multiple regression deals with the case where there is one dependent variable but more than one independent variables. So in my case I have 5 features (independent, Xs, predictors, etc) and 6 targets (dependents, Ys, responses, etc)
I have tried both statsmodel and scikit for multivariate and it seems like to me that they both just regress the individual target variables separately from the features. Just want to see and confirm if this is anyone else's experience and or expectation. I have read the documentation and it seems to be this way but not 100% sure.
As an example, if someone is trying to predict an athlete's throwing various balls and track maximum height, the X's could be:
X=[[Age, height, weight, BMI, YearsInSportsParticipation]]
y=[[maxAltitude_Basketball,maxAltitude_ScoccerBall,maxAltitude_Football,maxAltitude_shotputBall]]
both statsmodel and scikit would just loop each y separately from the group of Xs?

This seems sensible.  If you look at some of the formulas for the fitted regression coefficients, $y$ and $\beta$ turn from a vectors into matrices.  The computations are such that the columns of $B$ (the matrix of regression coefficients) would be single vectors of coefficients for the columns of $Y$ (the matrix of outcomes).  This would be like looping over outcomes.
What I am not certain about is how uncertainty is handled by either library.
